# Histogram with FASTA file

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics, plotting

I am new to Linux.
I have a FASTA file that looks something like this:

```
>scaffold1
AAGACATAATATTTTGGAGGAATTAAAAAATTTAAGATGTATTTTATTATACATGTATTTTATTTATAACATAAATAAACATCCCAAGGAAAAGCAGTAGCT
>scaffold2
AAGGATAAGTGTAGCTGAGGAATTAAAAAATTTAACAAATAAAATTAATGCAATTTATTTTTTCAAATAAAAATACACGGAGAAAAATAATTTGTAAATTTT
```

etc. This goes on to about 5000+ scaffolds.

I want to make a histogram with the scaffold lengths.
I read about Biopython etc. but I don't know anything about installing these programs. Is there a way to get a histogram with just the Linux commands (terminal) or with R?
Thank you

Comment: Surely you can do. But why not get happy with a tool especially designed for your needs? If you don't already have `python3` installed on your machine, do it with `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`, then `sudo pip install biopython` and you are ready to use it.

Comment: Are the scaffold sequences in your fasta file limited to a single line, or are there scaffolds with multiple lines of sequence?

Comment: Wait, you have R already? Did you try searching for "plot fasta length in R" or anything similar? There are _loads_ of bioinformatics libraries for R, I'm sure one can do it for you already.